# Saving and reading from specific parts of a .txt file

Tags: c#

Aspiring programmer here!

You can skip this part if you find it irrelevant.

---

Im currently working on a project where i give every program a username and i let people edit their own part of of each file. This will work more or less like onenote (great program), but i want to be able to restrict access to certian parts of it. I also need the file to be stored locally (on a shared location that is). In time i also want the files to be encrypted, but ill stick with the editing part of my question for now.

---

So my real problem:
I need people to be able to edit their part of a .txt file. The setup will probably look like this:

Document name:

Task 1: (Task name, like "Write a paragraph about Einstein"

User 1: (User 1s answer)

User 2: (User 2s answer and etc.)

Then ill follow up with more tasks / users. What i need to make my program understand is to read-only document name and other users answer, and read-write on their own part of the file.

What code can i use to accomplish this?

Comment: You really don't want to do this in a text file. Why not use a database?

Comment: Sounds like something you should probably use a database for instead of a text file. Just saying.

Comment: This has nothing to do with what code you are going to use but how you are going to use it, if you dont have sql you could always use xml.

Comment: Well, should i have a database running on my pc then? Currently got WampServer and MySQL, would this do? Gratefull for the quick replies :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do that in a text file. You'll have to spend a little bit more effort in solving that task. Use a database and manage those tasks in a table and the user responses in another table. That will shurely work much better, trust me.

Comment: Will WampServer and MySQL work? Had database oriented programming for half a year or so and still got the programms

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use a text based solution for this instead of a database I would look into XML files.

They give you the ability to structure a document and have capabilities of being queried by C# trough XPath or Linq to XML queries.

This [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) should get you started.

Comment: But you will not be able to "lock" parts of the xml file to prevent other users from changing it.

Comment: I wouldnt mind doing this as a database, i just hadnt thought of it at all. It would make it easier aswell with no files lying around on our shared servers.

Comment: Using a Database instead of a text file doesn't solve your problem of 'the user should only edit his own data'. That is a business requirement that you should enforce with some business rules in code

Comment: This is currently just to have at school (I dont like people messing up my one-note). Do i need any restricting at all? I'm not really afraid of any1 at my current school being able to send SQL queries at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yea a database (use an MSAccess MDB file if you don't have a SQL server) would be best for this.
However, if you really want to use a text file, what you do is 
1. Use System.IO to read the file and parse the file to get the piece of data you want them to edit (only read it out of the file, don't modify the file at this point).
2. Display the piece of data to them in a textbox or whatever.
3. After they've mdofied it, then read in the whole file into a variable
4. replace the old piece of data with the new data. in the variable.
5. output the entire variable back into the file and save and close it.

If this is REALLY what you want to do, i can post some code for you.

Comment: Look into SQL Server Express. For the love of all things holy, don't use Access.